# Jquery: Unable to convert Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

My backend is Django

django is sending string X like below

```
"[{'one': 'hi'}, {'one': 'hello'}]"
```

In Jquery, JSON.parse() doesn't work due to double quotes.it works only for single quotes surrounded with a value

I want to convert string X to js object..any help could help me ?

Comment: You can use eval("[{'one': 'hi'}, {'one': 'hello'}]") . But this is very bad practice.

Comment: How do you generate that string? It's not JSON. It seems the server-side script tries to generate the JSON manually. Fix the source. Every language has a tested API for generating JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is not a **[valid JSON](http://json.org/example.html)** , so instead **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** you can use **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**

```js
var str="[{'one': 'hi'}, {'one': 'hello'}]";

var obj=eval(str);

console.log(obj);
```

Or the string should be in **[valid JSON format](http://json.org/example.html)**, check your server side code and build valid JSON

```js
var str = '[{"one": "hi"}, {"one": "hello"}]';
//-----------^---^--^--^----^---^--^-----^---

var obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj);
```